# Improve performance of Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, apache-pig

I'm looking for a way to improve this regular expression:

```
^(?:([^.]+).?){6}_tid
```

This extracts the 6th field of a point.separated.string.of.arbitrary.lengths up to "_tid"

So if it looks like this:

```
mc11_7tev.138345.dgnol_tb6_m12u_140_140_110_2l_jimmy_susy.evgen.log.e825_tid431423_0
```

it should return

```
e825
```

Funnily enough, if I remove the _tid part of the regex `^(?:([^.]+).?){6}`, I get the performance I was looking for.. 1 to 2 seconds for a million strings to check.
With the _tid.. it takes up to 5 minutes.

Is there a better way to do this?

---

EDIT:
Ah, I forgot to mention, this is in Apache Pig, so everything should be in the regex clause.

Comment: Does it have to be REGEX? Or you just looking for a solution to do that fast as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the dot, try this

```
^(?:([^.]+)\.?){6}_tid
```

this way your regex has much less possibilities to match. The "." without escaping matches any character (without line break characters).

The other possibility I see is getting rid of the optional dot

```
^(?:[^.]+\.){5}([^.]+)_tid
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vpef)

Answer (score 1):

I would first split the String on `.`, get the 6th part, split it on `_`, get the first part:

```
s.split("\.")[5].split("_")[0];
```

Not tested!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, this is in Apache Pig, so everything should be in the regex clause.

Comment: Ups sorry.. :) My mistake... :) I should write:" 
Maybe you should correct your question, and include this information.." --> this was meant to Mario.. :) Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to run faster than yours:

```
^(?:[^.]+\.){5}([^.]+)_tid
```

Answer (score 1):

This one gives me the best performance results:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.([^_]+)_tid.*");
```

Comment: This loses the restriction that it must be in the 6th field.